# Creating a continuously updating custom control with proper undo management

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsundomanager

I am putting together a custom NSView that handles two values through bindings. I am propagating the values upon updates as outlined by Tom Dalling in the question [Can you manually implement Cocoa bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169097/can-you-manually-implement-cocoa-bindings). This all works fine.

In order to make the control update continuously, I update and propagate the values in the `-mouseDragged` method. Again, this works fine, but it registers the intermediate steps to the NSUndoManager, which I don't want. So, I tried issuing `disableUndoRegistration` in `-mouseDown` and then `enableUndoRegistration` in `mouseUp`. Naturally I update and propagate the results again.

No undo at all was registered, and I realized it's because my set function doesn't register an undo if the value is unchanged:

```
- (void)setX:(double)newX {
    if (newX != x) {
        [[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] setX:x];
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"x"];
        x = newX;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"x"];
    }
}
```

Since the `-mouseDragged` had already propagated the value, it didn't change when it was sent again in `-mouseUp`, so the undo was never recorded. I of course want it to undo to the place it was before the initial `-mouseDown`, so let's say I do this by storing that value in the control and then sending that one again in `-mouseUp`, before I send the new value. This of course still has the problem that I can see a flash of it going back to its old value.

I could fix this in the `-setX:` method, by checking if the undo manager is enabled and keeping a track of the old value. However, I should be able to accomplish this from within the control, since there are controls with this exact behaviour (like an NSSlider set to continuous).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just use `beginUndoGrouping` and `endUndoGrouping`?

---

P.S. If you're curious how Cocoa classes work internally, it can sometimes be helpful to check out the GNUstep implementions (NSUndoManager is in GNUstep Base, AppKit classes like NSSliderCell are in GNUstep GUI):

http://wwwmain.gnustep.org/resources/downloads.php?site=http%3A%2F%2Fftpmain.gnustep.org%2Fpub%2Fgnustep%2F#core

Comment: This works perfectly. I can't believe I missed something so fundamental. I'm a complete novice when it comes to the NSUndoManager. Thanks!