# Best way to bind custom NSView with custom NSObject

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding

I'm trying to bind a property from a custom NSView to another on a custom NSObject. Both properties are simple bool value.

As a newbie with custom binding i've read Apple Documentation and searched on stackoverflow.

So I created a custom NSView and a custom NSObject, added a bool property called 'enabled' to both and bind them with `[myCustomView bind:@"enabled" toObject:myObject withKeyPath:@"enabled" options:nil];`

My customView use the approach explained in this article http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/cocoa/implementing-your-own-cocoa-bindings/ to notify value's changes and prevent memory retain issues.

I started my app, it works ! Wonderful ... but it's only one way binding ! When I click my customView, the custom object's property is updated (right) but if the custom object's property value change, my custom view's property isn't updated (Grrrr)

I'm a bit confused because as far as i understood custom bindings, Apple recommendation is to manually implement bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options and register an observer to track property's value changes and Tom Dalling's approach says the opposite.

So what is the best way to bind my properties in a bi-directional way ?

Comment: "I've heard of two ways of doing something. I tried one of them and it didn't work. Now I'm all out of ideas!"

Comment: Do you change the value of your custom object's property in a KVO compliant way?

Comment: What do you mean by change the value of property in a kvo compliant way ? By registering an observer ?

Comment: How do you change the value of your custom object's property?

Comment: I simply assign a new value for my customObject's property. `customObject.enabled = value`

I also tried this syntax `[customObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:value] forKey:@"enabled"];` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775326/bindtoobjectwithkeypathoptions-is-one-way-binding) indicates that you just setup a symmetric binding going the other way. I haven't tried this, but it sounds like the following will work.

```
[myObject bind:@"enabled" toObject:myCustomView withKeyPath:@"enabled" options:nil];
```

Comment: I've already tried to setup the symmetric binding but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm a bit confused because as far as i understood custom bindings, Apple recommendation is to manually implement bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options and register an observer to track property's value changes and Tom Dalling's approach says the opposite.

You have to implement both. You have to observe `myObject` with keypath @"enabled" so when `myObject.enabled` changes you can change `myCustomView.enabled`. You have to set `myObject.enabled` when `myCustomView.enabled` changes.

See [Responding to Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/HowDoBindingsWork.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002373-196748)